# a number plus by gcd

Tags: elementary-number-theory, gcd-and-lcm

I write the number $6$ on the blackboard. At the $n^\text{th}$ step, an integer $k$ on the
board is replaced by $k + \gcd(n, k)$. Prove that at each step, the number on the blackboard increases either by $1$ or by a prime number.

These are something I have tried:
Actually, I have no idea for this question but I noticed that The difference can't be equal to $2$

Comment: what is the $1^{st}$ step?

Comment: $1$st step will be $6 \to 6+\gcd(6,1)\implies 6 \to 7$.

Comment: Interesting. Where did you get this? If you start with 4 instead of 6 then it fails at step 40 when k=64.

Comment: @DanielWainfleet I did check (being wary, as per https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/16774/contest-problem-policy) but this problem has been on the Internet for years (though I could not see where it originally came from). Also, it doesn't seem that the case $4$ is any different from $6$, can you please check your calculation?

Comment: With a pencil, I erred at step 11.

Comment: Your link is to a policy statement. I like this Q. If you can give a source, someone might track down an answer or some useful info.

Comment: Ok but if you start with $k_0= 531$ it fails after 20 iterations...I guess you want to prove it for 6? Unless I messed up the script obviously...

Comment: It can be proved that it works for any initial $k_0$ for the first 7 iterations at least, after that it becomes tedious... It is easy to prove it always works for $k_0=1,2$

Comment: There is a brilliant video on youtube answering this question except starting at 7 https://m.youtube.com/watch?v=OpaKpzMFOpg

Comment: Thanks for posting it! I think he starts at $k_1=7$ which is equivalent to starting with $k_0=6$ in our case.

Answer (score 1):

The game starts with $K_0 \geq 3$. At step $n$ we have:
$$K_n = K_{n-1}+gcd(n, K_{n-1})$$ for $n=1,2,3,...$

Therefore at each step $n$, we define a jump $$g(n) = K_n - K_{n-1} = gcd(n, K_{n-1})$$
**Lemma 1:**

$\forall K_0 \geq 3$ there exists a $n \geq 2 $ such that $g(n) > 1$

**Proof:**

Assume on the contrary that $g(i) = 1$ for $i=2,3,...$
At step $i-1$ then we have $K_{i-1}= K_0 + i-1$.
Now take $i$ such that $K_0 \equiv 1 \mod{i}$. (Note that such $i$ exists, for example take $i=K_0-1 \geq 2$).
At step $i$ we get $$K_i = K_{i-1} + gcd (i, K_{i-1}) = K_0 + i-1 + gcd(i, K_0 + i-1)$$
Therefore $g(i)=i \geq 2$ given that $i | K_0+i-1$ and this is a contradiction.

**Lemma 2:**

$\forall K_0 \geq 3$, the minimum $i$ such that $g(i)>1$ is prime. In particular we have $g(i)=g(p)=p$ with p prime.

**Proof:**

By the previous lemma, there exist a first jump at step $i$ such that $g(i) > 1$.
Let's assume on the contrary that the first jump bigger than $1$ happens at step $c$ with $c$ composite, i.e. $g(c)>1$.

We have $K_c = K_{c-1}+ gcd(c, K_{c-1}) = K_0+c-1 + gcd(c, K_0+c-1)$.
Therefore $gcd(c, K_{c-1}) =pt$ where we take $p$ to be the smallest prime dividing $gcd(c, K_{c-1})$ so that we must have $p<c$.
Hence $K_{c-1} = K_0 + c-1 \equiv 0 \mod{p}$. In other words we have that $$K_0 \equiv 1 \mod{p}$$.
But then $g(p)=p$ since
$K_p = K_{p-1} + gcd(p, K_{p-1})$ with $K_{p-1} = K_0+p-1$
This is a contradiction as we have assumed that the first jump bigger than $1$ was only happening at $c>p$.

From this Lemma it follows that the first jump bigger than $1$ happens at a prime $p$ so that $g(p)=gcd(p, K_{p-1})=p$

**UPDATE**: OK I found a paper from professor Eric Rowland that solves this problem (see https://ericrowland.github.io/, in particular https://ericrowland.github.io/papers/A_natural_prime-generating_recurrence.pdf).

I am reporting it below with some expansion of steps and in a less generic form, changing a bit the initial hypothesis.

I have to say it is elementary and brilliant, thank you Eric.

**Rowland Theorem**:

$\forall K_0 \geq 3$, let the integer $n_1 \geq 2$ be such that $K_{n_1} = 3n_1$. Let $q$ be the smallest prime number which divides $K_{n_1}-(n_1+1) = 2n_1-1$.

Let $n_2$ be the smallest integer greater than $n_1$ such that $g(n_2)>1$.

Then $n_2=n_1 + \frac{q-1}{2}$, $g(n_2)=q$ and $K_{n_2} = 3n_2$

**Proof:**

Suppose that for $n_1 \geq 2$ we have that $k_{n_1}=3n_1$. First we note that with our choice of $k_{n_1}$ and $n_1$ we must have $q > 2$, so $q$ is odd and $\frac{q-1}{2}$ is indeed an integer.

Let $c=n_2 - n_1$. We want to prove that $c=\frac{q-1}{2}$.
First we note that for $1\leq i \leq c$, we have:
$$g(n_1+i)=gcd(n_1+i, 3n_1+i-1)$$
Using the properties of the gcd we also have that:
$$g(n_1+i) | (3n_1+i-1-n_1-i)=(2n_1-1)$$
$$g(n_1+i) | (3(n_1+i)-(3n_1+i-1)) = (2i+1)$$.

We prove $c\geq \frac{q-1}{2}$:

Note that $g(n_2)=g(n_1+c)|2n_1-1$ since we have shown above that $g(n_1+i) | 2n_1-1$.
But $q$ is the smallest prime which divides $2n_1-1$ so $q\leq g(n_1+c)$.

Also $g(n_1+c)| (2c+1)$ since we have shown above that $g(n_1+i) | 2i+1$ so $g(n_1+c)\leq (2c+1)$. Putting it all together we have then:

$$q \leq g(n_1+c)\leq (2c+1)$$

In other words we have shown that $c\geq \frac{q-1}{2}$

We now prove $c\leq \frac{q-1}{2}$:

We know that for $1 \leq i < \frac{q-1}{2}$, we must have $g(n_1+i)=1$ since we have proved that $c\geq \frac{q-1}{2}$ and the first "jump" bigger than $1$ must happen after $n_1$ at $n_2=n_1+c$ by our assumption.

We show that $g(n_1+ \frac{q-1}{2}) > 1$ which proves that $c\leq \frac{q-1}{2}$ :

$$g(n_1+ \frac{q-1}{2})=gcd(n_1+\frac{q-1}{2}, 3n_1+\frac{q-1}{2} -1)$$

Expanding the expressions we get:
$$g(n_1+ \frac{q-1}{2})=gcd(\frac{2n_1+q-1)}{2}, \frac{3(2n_1-1)+q}{2}) $$

By definition $q|2n_1-1$ and by linearity we get $q|2n_1+q-1$ and $q|3(2n_1-1)+q$ since $q>2$ (so $q$ does not divides $2$), therefore we must have that

$$q|gcd(\frac{2n_1+q-1)}{2}, \frac{3(2n_1-1)+q}{2})=g(n_1+ \frac{q-1}{2})$$

This proves that $g(n_1+ \frac{q-1}{2}) \geq q >1$

We have then estabilished that $c=\frac{q-1}{2}$

Now we prove that $g(n_2)=q$. We have shown already that $q|g(n_1+ \frac{q-1}{2})$. But we also know that $g(n_1+c)=g(n_1+ \frac{q-1}{2})| (2c+1) = q$ so we have

$$q=g(n_1+c)=g(n_2)$$

Finally just substituting to the definition of $k_{n_2}$ we get $$K_{n_2} = 3n_1+\frac{q-1}{2}-1+q$$
We have that $n_1 + \frac{q-1}{2} = n_2$ therefore we can write $K_{n_2}$ as follows:

$$K_{n_2}=n_1+\frac{q-1}{2} + 2n_1+q-1=n_2+2n_2 = 3n_2$$

Now for $k_0=6$ we have the first jump bigger than $1$ for the integer $n_1=5$, and $K_{n_1}=15=3n_1$, with $g(n_1)=5$ prime. So we can then apply the Theorem inductively from that point onwards and we have proved what we wanted.

Comment: In case this is of use:  *Mathematica*:  `f[0] = 6;
f[n_] := f[n - 1] + GCD[n, f[n - 1]];`